# Why does the Laplace transform of $\ln(t)$ exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

In my lecture script for Complex Analysis the following requirements are stated for a function to have a laplace transform:

(1) $f(t)=0$ for all $t < 0$

(2) There exist a real $\sigma$ and a positive $M$ so that
$$\forall t>0, |f(t)| \leq Me^{\sigma t}$$

(3) $f(t)$ is piece-wise continuous and the left and right limits exist at each discontinuity. Also $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(t)$$ exists.

An exercise was to determine if the Laplace Transform of $\ln(t)$ exists, and if it does, determine it.

I concluded that it does not exists because $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0^+}\ln(t) = -\infty$

However the solution mentions that the Transform exists, and determines it to be:
$$-\frac{1}{s}(\ln(s)+\gamma)$$

with $\gamma$ being the Euler-Mascheroni Constant.

Could someone explain what I am missing here?

Comment: Condition (3) is too restrictive. $f$ should be in $L^1[0,\infty)$ or at least the integral exists on $[t,\infty)$ as $t\to0^+$. Laplace transforms of discontinuous functions (eg [step function](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/laplace-transform/properties-of-laplace-transform/v/laplace-transform-of-the-unit-step-function)) are legitimate.

Comment: @user Is the exercise also from your script?

Comment: Those conditions are sufficient, not necessary. And necessary conditions only apply to the Laplace transform being in some particular class of functions, not to it "existing" generally. One can extend it to distributions, and then it exists for things far worse than the logarithm or even non-integrable functions like $\frac1t$. The rule of thumb is that it *always* exists, the only question is how well-behaved it turns out to be.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Not the script, but from the excercise set provided by the professor.